# ImageButton padding added when scaling

Tags: android

It is difficult to explain by words so I will show you an image to illustrate the problem

[image: image imagebutton padding added scaling scaleType]

As you see, a paddingTop and paddingBottom has been added after scaling the ImageView as "centerInside".

I don't like it because this way I lose control from the design.

I know I can put android:marginTop="-5dp" but it's not a good solution because it might not work the same in every device.

Here is the code of the ImageButton

```
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/login_button_twitter" 
            android:src="@drawable/login_twitter_button_es"
            android:layout_above="@+id/login_button_account" 
            android:background="@null"   
            android:text="@string/access_twitter"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
             />
```

Do you know why it is adding this space if I have set the layout_height and layout_width as wrap_content?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by that the image is to big for the boundaries.

Try adding the following line to your ImageButton

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

This will cause the boundaries of the View to wrap its content.